Making a Histogram using an Array of integers
I’m trying to make a method that takes a String and then fills an array based on the frequency of letters in the string where the array[0] is the number of A’s etc. Then it takes the array and prints out a histogram with all the letters with an asterisk above them in columns for each time a letter appears in the string. I was able to code the part that gets the amount of each letter in a string but I have no idea how to print out the histogram.
void drawHistogram() {
    int[] frequency = new int[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(text.charAt(i))) {
            frequency[Character.getNumericValue(Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(i))) - 10] += 1;
        }
    }
}

text is a string variable from the class.
For example, if text = "I love problem-solving.", the program should print this histogram
                      *     *   
        *       *     *     *             *           
  *     *   *   *     * * * * *   * *     *       
---------------------------------------------------
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

There should be one asterisk above b, g, m, n, p, r and s. Two above e, i and v. Three above l and o.

BTW char is an integral type, you can do Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(i)) - 'a' to get the index, on the other side, using getNumericValue() does not need toLowerCase()

When I did - ‘a’ it would give me an index out of bounds error saying it tried to access index -79, but thanks for the info about not needing toLowerCase.

note: I meant frequency[Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(i))-'a'], and not frequency[Character.getNumericValue(Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(i))) - 'a'] (or similar) - that is, without getNumericalValue() (( kind of logical 'a' - 'a' is zero, 'b'-'a' is one, 'c'-'a' is two, ... ))

In order to print the histogram as columns, with the letters below the columns, you first need to get the frequencies of each letter and also find the maximum frequency. Then you iterate through the letters and if that letter's frequency is not less than the maximum frequency, print a *, otherwise print a space. Then reduce the maximum by one and repeat – until the maximum reaches zero.
public class Histogram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "I love problem-solving.";
        int[] frequency = new int[26];
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(text.charAt(i))) {
                int ndx = Character.getNumericValue(Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(i))) - 10;
                frequency[ndx] += 1;
                if (frequency[ndx] > max) {
                    max = frequency[ndx];
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = max; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < frequency.length; j++) {
                if (frequency[j] >= i) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("-".repeat(51));
        System.out.println("a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z");
    }
}

Here is the output:
                      *     *                       
        *       *     *     *             *         
  *     *   *   *     * * * * *   * *     *         
---------------------------------------------------
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

I suggest that you step through the code with a debugger in order to better understand how it works.

Here is one method.
The idea is to create individual strings of the accumulated histogram values.  This facilitates the final printing of the histogram.

First create a List<String> and populate it with the base lines of dashes and alphabet.
Then create a linked list of the text characters.
Now iterate over the text characters until the list is empty.

Each letter is set in its appropriate position in the current StringBuilder.
The purpose of the HashSet is to ensure that one letter of a given type is counted per pass. The iterator allows removal of that letter.  Once the first pass is done and used letters have been removed, reallocate the set and repeat.
static String chars = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";
static String dashes = "-".repeat(chars.length());

public static void drawHistogram(String text) {

    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>(List.of(chars, dashes));

    List<Integer> textChars = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int c : text.toCharArray()) {
        textChars.add(c);
    }

    while (!textChars.isEmpty()) {
        Set<Character> notSeenThisRound = new HashSet<>();
        // initialize the current row to blanks
        StringBuilder currentRow = new StringBuilder(" ".repeat(chars.length()));
        Iterator<Integer> it = textChars.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            
            // retrieve and convert to lower case character
            char c = (char) (it.next().intValue() | 32);
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                
                // ensure it's only processed once
                if (notSeenThisRound.add(c)) {
                    it.remove();
                    currentRow.setCharAt((c - 'a') * 2, '*');
                }
                continue;
            }
            
            // remove non-alphabetic characters.
            it.remove();
        }
        // add the new row
        rows.add(currentRow.toString());
    }

    for (int i = rows.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
           System.out.println(rows.get(i));
    }
}

prints
                      *     *                      
        *       *     *     *             *        
  *     *   *   *     * * * * *   * *     *        
---------------------------------------------------
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

